# classification algorithms for high dimension dataset

Tags: classification

I'm new to machine learning, I need advice on what kind of classification algorithms and techniques can be used to deal with high dimension datasets (129 rows and 1900 columns) for classification problem.

Answer (score 0):

Algorithms will remain same as any other classification but you can do the try following:

1. Do dimensionality reduction using PCA to reduce dimensions
2. Use forward or backward selection algorithms
3. Remove highly correlated variable
4. Use L1 regularisation with high alpha value as it does features selection intinsically